# Shiny - object from reactive expression not found when used in loglm

Tags: r, shiny, mosaic-plot

I created a shiny app, in which I want to display the residual of a log-linear model using a mosaic plot.  I need to use the data from a reactive expression and pass it to `loglm`.  It seem pretty strait forward, but when I do that I get the following error : "objet 'mod' introuvable".

I've already figured which line is causing the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.  Running the code below as is should work fine.
However, uncomment the line `# mod <-  loglm( formula = reformulate(f), data = mod )`, in server and you should get the same error I get.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Shiny Viz!"),

  fluidRow( class= "R1",
        tabsetPanel(type= "pills",

                    tabPanel("Log-linear model",
                             fluidRow( 
                               column(3, offset=1,
                                      selectInput("model", label= "Choose model to fit:",
                                                  choices= c("(SPT)","(SP,ST,PT)","(ST,PT)","(SP,PT)","(SP,ST)")),
                                      selectInput("type", label= "Visualise the expected or observed values?",
                                                  choices = c("observed", "expected")), 
                                      sliderInput("n_breaks", label = "Degree Celcius per bin:",
                                                  min = .5, max = 5, value = 1, step = .5)),
                               column(8, plotOutput("loglinear.mosaic",  height= "600px") ) 
                             )))) 
 )




library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(vcd)
library(vcdExtra)

server <- function(input, output) {  

 # Create data
 DF <- data.table( Temp = runif(5000, 0, 30),
                Presence = factor(rbinom(5000, 1, runif(20, 0.1, 0.60))), 
                Period =  factor(as.integer(runif(5000, 1, 9))) ) 

 # Reactive expression
 loglinear <- reactive({  
   DF[ , Temperature.category := cut_interval(Temp, length= input$n_breaks)]


   Tab <- xtabs(formula= ~ Period + Temperature.category + Presence,
                      data = DF)


   return(Tab)
 })


 # mosaic plot
 output$loglinear.mosaic <- renderPlot({

   mod <- loglinear()

   f <- switch(input$model,
            "(SPT)"= c("Presence*Period*Temperature.category"),
            "(SP,ST,PT)" = c("Presence*Period","Presence*Temperature.category","Period*Temperature.category"), 
            "(ST,PT)" = c("Presence*Temperature.category","Period*Temperature.category"),
            "(SP,PT)" = c("Presence*Period","Period*Temperature.category"),
            "(SP,ST)" = c("Presence*Period","Presence*Temperature.category"))

    # mod <-  loglm( formula = reformulate(f), data = mod )

    mosaic(mod, 
         gp= shading_hcl,
         spacing = spacing_highlighting,
         type= input$type,
         labeling_args= list(offset_varnames = c(right = 1, left=.5), 
                             offset_labels = c(right = .1),
                             set_varnames = c(Temperature.category="Temperature", Period="Period",
                                            Presence="Status")),
         set_labels=list(Presence = c("Ab","Pr")), 
         margins = c(right = 5, left = 3, bottom = 1, top =3))

  })

} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I guess that is a problem with the data format that `loglm()` allows

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be related to the data format, since the code works perfectly fine out of the shiny app. Moreover, the `loglm` help page say that the "data" argument can be the result of a call to `xtabs`, as is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found what is causing the problem with `loglm`, but I've figured another way of getting the result I wanted.

I used `glm` to fit the model instead of `loglm`, then used `mosaic.glm` from the `vcdExtra` package to create the mosaic plot. The code is pretty much the same except that the data as to be a `data.frame` and the column 'Temperature.category', 'Period' and 'Presence' must be factor to be used with `glm`.

However, I am still clueless as to why `loglm` can't find the object 'mod', but `glm` can?  I'd realy want to know the reason. Since my answers doesn't answer that question, I'll accept an other answer if someone has an explanation.

Here's what the code using `glm`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Viz!"),

  fluidRow( class= "R1",
        tabsetPanel(type= "pills",

                    tabPanel("Log-linear model",
                             fluidRow( 
                               column(3, offset=1,
                                      selectInput("model", label= "Choose model to fit:",
                                                  choices= c("(SPT)","(SP,ST,PT)","(ST,PT)","(SP,PT)","(SP,ST)")),
                                      selectInput("type", label= "Visualise the expected or observed values?",
                                                  choices = c("observed", "expected")), 
                                      sliderInput("n_breaks", label = "Degree Celcius per bin:",
                                                  min = .5, max = 5, value = 1, step = .5)),
                               column(8, plotOutput("loglinear.mosaic",  height= "800px") ) 
                             )))) 
)

library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(vcd)
library(vcdExtra)


server <- function(input, output) {  

   DF <- data.table( Temp = runif(5000, 0, 30),
                 Presence = factor(rbinom(5000, 1, runif(20, 0.1, 0.60))), 
                 Period =  factor(as.integer(runif(5000, 1, 9)) ) ) 


  # data to data.frame format
  loglinear <- reactive({ 

    DF[ , Temperature.category := cut_interval(Temp, length= input$n_breaks)]

    # add 'Freq' column
    dat <- data.frame(as.table(xtabs(formula= ~ Period + Temperature.category + Presence,
             data = DF)), stringsAsFactors = T) 


    return(dat)
   })


  # mosaic plot
  output$loglinear.mosaic <- renderPlot({

    mod <- loglinear()

    f <- switch(input$model,
            "(SPT)"= c("Presence*Period*Temperature.category"),
            "(SP,ST,PT)" = c("Presence*Period","Presence*Temperature.category","Period*Temperature.category"), 
            "(ST,PT)" = c("Presence*Temperature.category","Period*Temperature.category"),
            "(SP,PT)" = c("Presence*Period","Period*Temperature.category"),
            "(SP,ST)" = c("Presence*Period","Presence*Temperature.category"))

    # fit model using glm
    mod.glm <- glm(formula = reformulate(f, response = "Freq"), data= mod, family= poisson)

    mosaic.glm(mod.glm, 
               formula =  ~ Temperature.category + Period + Presence,
               gp= shading_hcl,
               spacing = spacing_highlighting,
               type= input$type,
               labeling_args= list(rot_labels = c(left = 0,  right = 0),
                                 offset_varnames = c(left=1.5, right = 1), 
                                 offset_labels = c(left=.5, right = .1),
                                 set_varnames = c(Temperature.category="Temperature", Period="Period",
                                                Presence="Status")),
             set_labels=list(Presence = c("Ab","Pr")), 
             margins = c(right = 5, left = 4, bottom = 1, top =3))

   })

}
```